# Installshield Run EXE only during install

Tags: executable, installshield

I have another question regarding exe's and custom actions within Installshield.

I currently have a set of custom actions which launch executables in silent mode..

In the return process, it is set for Synchronous(Check exit code) mode, and it is set for a Deferred Execution in System Context.

My question is the following:

When I install my application, it is fine. It runs through the installers and installs the prerequisites. My problem is when I want to uninstall the application from the machine, because it runs through the same installers again (and trys to install them again, even though we are uninstalling).

I looked all around, and cannot find a good work-around for this.

Anyone have experience with this and know of a method of getting the installs to only run when the installer runs and not when uninstalling?

Much Appreciated...

Thanks
-Kyle

Answer (score 3):

You have to condition your CustomAction to "Not Installed". The condition "Not Installed" ensures the action runs only during a first-time installation, and not during maintenance mode or uninstallation.

Check this link from Flexera: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/PDF/IS_Tip_Executable-Custom-Actions-for-MSIs.pdf

Answer (score 2):

How about a custom action condition like "Not Installed".  This means it will only run on a first-time installation, not "maintenance" or "uninstall".

Comment: It would also run during a Major Upgrade which may not be desirable.